# Remix solidity does not return result on private ethereum chain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, remix, go-ethereum

I have just started learning ethereum and remix, and this question might seem stupid to you.

I tried following codes on javascript vm embedded inside remix ide, and it works totally fine, but it fails to return the string on a private chain I set up early, even though it does not report any errors. The solidity code I'm using is as follows.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
contract Greeter {

    function greet() external pure returns(string memory) {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }

}
```

Can anybody provide some idea where I might go wrong?
P.S. I have set `miner.start()`, and use following script to start the private chain:

````
geth --datadir data --networkid 18810100026 --port 60000 --rpc  --rpcport 8100 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --bootnodes enode://****73c2e56ed109f7ab559bc0df26e01e4a72c4eef660d0853e8c241a737b43bd7f7da32d22e272fe187f7063d9559691@****:30301 --rpcapi eth,web3,miner,admin,personal,net --rpccorsdomain "*"```

geth version is 1.7.3
````

[screenshot of contract running on private chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0JUB.png)

[screenshot of contract running on javascript VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKW1v.png)

Comment: Does greet function not work?

Comment: @MortezaFarhadi No, it does not work. The function can be called, with no error, but the returned string "Hello world" does not show

Comment: i use greet in new contract and that is worked !

Comment: how to call greet function ?

Comment: I do not know how to call it in your env, but in mine, it only needs one simple click.

Comment: yes. in remix with click to greet button called function. and in my ide returned "Hello world"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there were two fact that might lead to such an error

1. I did not update the `geth` to the current latest version.
2. I did not initialize the genesis block correctly.

So I made two modifications to solve such a problem

1. Update the `geth` to 1.10.17
2. add two lines to the genesis json file automatically generated by `puppeth`,
   which are as follows

```
{
  "config": {
    ...
    "byzantiumBlock": 4,
    "constantinopleBlock": 5,
    ...
  },
...
```

The problem was solved thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

i think your contract is ok!

i copy your code in to new contract on Remix 0.23.3, and return greet function: "Hello, World!"

Maybe you use remix ide in another version or your ide has bugs.
I suggest you use another brower for remix or another ide for solidity like hardhat https://hardhat.org/

my result for greet:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is probably not with the contract but with the blockchain I setup on my own. I also tried on Javascript VM as you did and it worked fine. The problem is that the string cannot be returned when I set the environment to Web3 provider, which is as <a href=https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKW1v.png>This</a> shows.